# Giving custom attribute to asciidoctor gradle task issued from preceding task

Tags: git, gradle, asciidoctor

i'm trying to retrieve my latest git tag with gradle task in order to use it in my asciidoctor docs. Even if my task succeed, my asciidoctor custom attribute is always empty. This is how I retrieved my latest git tag:

```
project.ext {
    latestTag= 'N/A'
}
task retrieveLatestTag {
   doLast {

       new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
           def result = exec {
              commandLine('git',  'rev-list',  '--tags', '--max-count=1')
              standardOutput = os
           }
           ext.latestTagName = os.toString().trim()
       }

   } 
}
task setLastStableVersion {
   dependsOn retrieveLatestTag
   doLast {

       new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
           def result = exec {
               commandLine('git',  'describe',  '--tags', retrieveLatestTag.latestTagName)
               standardOutput = os
           }
           project.ext.latestTag = os.toString().trim()
       }

   }
}
```

And now here is my asciidoctor task :

```
asciidoctor {
   dependsOn setLastStableVersion
   attributes \
    'build-gradle' : file('build.gradle'),
    'source-highlighter': 'coderay',
    'imagesdir': 'images',
    'toc': 'left',
    'toclevels': '4',
    'icons': 'font',
    'setanchors': '',
    'idprefix': '',
    'idseparator': '-',
    'docinfo1': '',
    'tag': project.latestTag
}
```

My custom property tag is always "N/A" like the default value I set first even though my tag is successfully retrieved. Has anyone tried to do something like this before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is the fact, that `asciidoctor` is configured at the configuration phase, since `setLastStableVersion` is declared with `doLast` closure, which is executed during execution phase.

The reason you've got no value is the fact, that configuration happens before execution and when `asciidoctor` is getting configured, no `setLastStableVersion` task, nor `retrieveLatestTag` are executed.

You don't need to have a task to get some your git tag, just remove `doLast` from your tasks or better place your logic out of any task, since you need it every time your build is configure, with the same order as follows:

```
new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
       def result = exec {
          commandLine('git',  'rev-list',  '--tags', '--max-count=1')
          standardOutput = os
       }
       project.ext.latestTagName = os.toString().trim()
   }

new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
       def result = exec {
           commandLine('git',  'describe',  '--tags', latestTagName)
           standardOutput = os
       }
       project.ext.latestTag = os.toString().trim()
   }

asciidoctor {
   dependsOn setLastStableVersion
   attributes \
    'build-gradle' : file('build.gradle'),
    'source-highlighter': 'coderay',
    'imagesdir': 'images',
    'toc': 'left',
    'toclevels': '4',
    'icons': 'font',
    'setanchors': '',
    'idprefix': '',
    'idseparator': '-',
    'docinfo1': '',
    'tag': project.latestTag
}
```

And [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) you can read about build lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, It works like a charm ! As I am new to gradle, I was not really aware about those phases, thanks again for the link.